# How to set global variable with UIColor class

Tags: iphone, global-variables, uicolor, uibackgroundcolor

i am developing on iPhone application. in this app i have 4 different views. in all views i set background color. see bellow code

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(238.0f/255.0f) green:(251.0f/255.0f) blue:(255.0f/255.0f) alpha:0.8f];
```

i am testing various colors for background color. when i have to change any colour i need to change in all view controllers. instead of that can i make global variable for this ? i don't know how to set UIColor in global variable. please suggest me some ideas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Very simple.

In AppDelegate.h:

```
#define kGlobalColor [UIColor colorWithRed:(238.0f/255.0f) green:(251.0f/255.0f) blue:(255.0f/255.0f) alpha:0.8f]
```

In ViewControllers:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

self.view.backgroundColor = kGlobalColor;
```

Comment: i use above answer. but this give me an error.
**Use of undeclared identifier 'kGlobalColor'**

Comment: Don't forget to import constant file in view controller, in this case AppDelegate.h

Comment: Google for subject: how to properly define in Objective C

Answer (score 0):

create `constant.h` file of `NSObject` and define this color globally

**#define globalColor [UIColor colorWithRed:(238.0f/255.0f) green:(251.0f/255.0f) blue:(255.0f/255.0f) alpha:0.8f];**

and when you want to use it just import the constant file other wise 2 option is bellow..

**Second Option**

in `AppDelegate.h` file just property synthesize one variable of UIColor like bellow..

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{
   ///your Data
   UIColor *globalColor;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain)  UIColor *globalColor;
```

and synthesize in .m file like bellow..

```
@syntesize globalColor;
```

and in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method just asssign color to this variable..

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
         globalColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(238.0f/255.0f) green:(251.0f/255.0f) blue:(255.0f/255.0f) alpha:0.8f];

}
```

and when you want to use this color use like this..

```
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
   self.view.backgroundColor = appDelegate.globalColor;
```

Comment: This is possible but not the optimal way to do this.

Comment: ya mate so i also give alternate option for this my first option is constant file mate.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Better than using a global variable is to extend `UIColor`. Make a category with a constructor, that provides your color:

UIColor+mycolor.h:

```
@interface UIColor (mycolor)
+ (UIColor*) myColor;
@end
```

UIColor+mycolor.m:

```
+ (UIColor*) systemBlue
{
return [UIColorcolorWithRed:(238.0f/255.0f) green:(251.0f/255.0f) blue:(255.0f/255.0f) alpha:0.8f];
 }
```