# Assigning UIColor values to macros

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros, global-variables, uicolor

This question refers to this SO post: [How to set global variable with UIColor class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493598/how-to-set-global-variable-with-uicolor-class)

The accepted answer suggests defining a macro like so:

***AppDelegate header:***

```
// AppDelegate.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#define black = [UIColor blackColor]
#define myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(238.0f/255.0f) green:(251.0f/255.0f) blue:(255.0f/255.0f) alpha:0.8f]

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@end
```

***ViewController implementation:***

```
// ViewController.m
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  ...

  // they both give the same error, 
  // with or without semi-colons
  // self.view.backgroundColor = black;
  self.view.backgroundColor = myColor;

}

@end
```

However, Xcode keeps popping these two exceptions:

**Expected expression**

**Expression is not assignable**

I've seen other suggestions using methods, but this approach fits my requirements best.

What could be causing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I define constant values of UIColor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718507/how-do-i-define-constant-values-of-uicolor)

Comment: @Yuyutsu: Not exactly; those solutions utilised method implementations. I'm interested in constant definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing to understand in this context is that a preprocessor macro only **replaces** (really, *1-to-1 replaces*) the code for the macro at compile time, thus your error-generating code actually looks like this to the compiler:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = = [UIColor colorWithRed:(238.0f/255.0f) green:(251.0f/255.0f) blue:(255.0f/255.0f) alpha:0.8f];
```

You can see for yourself that this doesn't make sense!

Be sure to remove the *assign operator* (`=`) when you define a macro that you want to use:

```
#define black [UIColor blackColor]
#define myColor [UIColor colorWithRed:(238.0f/255.0f) green:(251.0f/255.0f) blue:(255.0f/255.0f) alpha:0.8f]
```

Then replacing the macro name `myColor` actually delivers the desired result to the compiler:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(238.0f/255.0f) green:(251.0f/255.0f) blue:(255.0f/255.0f) alpha:0.8f]; // myColor has been replaced with the content of the macro
```

Comment: I missed that in the original post, and in all the other documents that I read on macro definitions. *Willful blindness perhaps?* Thank you nburk. Selected this as the accepted answer for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this , This is working for me ....

```
#define customBlueColour [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:181.0/255.0 blue:237.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

Comment: Thank you. Don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this

```
#define black [UIColor blackColor]
#define myColor [UIColor colorWithRed:(238.0f/255.0f) green:(251.0f/255.0f) blue:(255.0f/255.0f) alpha:0.8f]
```

Comment: It's actually in the original post that I copied. Apparently I copied it wrong. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a single global macro for all colours

```
#define getColor(_r_, _g_, _b_, _a_) [UIColor colorWithRed:_r_/255.0 green:_g_/255.0 blue:_b_/255.0 alpha:_a_]
```

User anywhere just by passing **Red Green Blue Alpha** Values

```
self.view.backgroundColor = getColor(238.0f, 251.0f, 255.0f , 1.0f);
```